# Backup file still overwrites the existing one(not expire)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-backups

I am using the following command to back up database

```
BACKUP DATABASE name
TO DISK = '...'
WITH INIT
```

The old one does not expire (0 for database retention day), (I know I could omit this or using `WITH NOINIT`) just want to know why specifying `WITH INIT` still overwrite the **unexpired** one? It is checking either database expired or the media set name, if expire, then overwrite, isn't it?

Comment: Well `INIT` or `NOINIT(default)` determines whether to overwrite or append backup. You using `WITH INIT` will always overwrite the backup, it does not care whether media has been expired or not.

Comment: @M.Ali: My reading of the documentation is that the interaction of INIT and NOSKIP (specified implicitly here as it's the default) is that NOSKIP trumps and specifying INIT shouldn't overwrite the backup if it's still valid (i.e. the expiration date hasn't passed).

Comment: @M.Ali, when you check the MS documentation for `BACKUP`, it says the `WITH INIT` will do the conditional overwrite if the backup expired and Media name matches

Comment: @BenThul, do you have any idea why it is still overwriting the current unexpired one? I did not specify any `expiredate` or `retainday`

Comment: @LONG: I'm not able to reproduce what you're seeing. Can you confirm that the backup that you think should have an expiration date indeed does? You can do this with the `restore headeronly from disk = '«your file here»'` command

Comment: @BenThul, it returns `NULL` for `ExpirationDate`

Comment: If you ran that command against the file that you expect to be protected by an expiration date, it's *not* protected which explains the behavior you're seeing.